# how to +5hours date in query select laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql, timestamp

I have a problem like this. Hope anyone can help, thanks a lot!!!
I want +5 hours for start_date, while start_date is not added time will not be retrieved

mycode:

```
$data = Ticket::
                selectRaw(strtotime('+5 hours','start_date'))
                ->limit($request->limit)
                ->offset($request->offset)
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 4):

you can define An Accessor with start_date in **Ticket** model

```php
use Carbon\Carbon;
...
    /**
     * Get the start date.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStartDateAttribute($value)
    {
        return Carbon::parse($value)->addHours(5);
    }
```

And remove select from query

```php
$data = Ticket::limit($request->limit)
                ->offset($request->offset)
                ->get();
```

and if you use start_date attribute this will return value plus 5 hours

```php
$ticket->start_date
```

Please be aware that the above method will override start date in all places you use it, so if you want to use it only in one place, change Accessor method to another attribute.

```php
public function getStartDateAddingHoursAttribute($value)
{
   return Carbon::parse($value)->addHours(5);
}
```

and call it with

```php
$ticket->start_date_adding_hours
```

Comment: Very nice solution, I'd like to add that this will only work if he has default column types like **(date / datetime / timestamp)** otherwise he needs to call **Carbon::createFromFormat()**